# Cordova, jQuery, AngularJS project structure

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

please help a newbie.

I started a project using Cordova, jQuery mobile and angularJS to build a android app and i wonder if this structure is ok.
index.js boot app, and app.js file contains logic. I don't know if it is a good idea put all in one only file.

What do you think about it?
Could you please advise on how to better organize my code?

Thanks in advance and here are structure and files, Regards!

Tree www folder is:

```
|-- css
|   |-- app.css
|   |-- app-theme.min.css
|   |-- images
|   |   |-- ajax-loader.gif
|   |   `-- refresh-black.png
|   |-- jquery.mobile.icons.min.css
|   |-- jquery.mobile.structure.min.css
|   `-- normalize.css
|-- img
|   |-- logo.png
|   `-- profile.png
|-- index.html
|-- js
|   |-- app.js
|   |-- index.js
|   `-- lib
|       |-- angular.min.js
|       |-- angular-route.min.js
|       |-- angular-touch.min.js
|       |-- jquery.min.js
|       `-- jquery.mobile.min.js
`-- templates
    |-- capturePhoto.html
    `-- main.html
```

index.js:

```
(function init() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){ app.init(); }, false);
}());
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';

var app = {
    init: function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        this.angular.config();
        this.angular.mainControllers();
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['exampleApp']);
    },
    angular: {
        config: function() {
            angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngTouch', 'exampleControllers']).config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                  when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                    controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
                  }).
                  when('/action/capturePhoto', {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/capturePhoto.html',
                        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
                  }).
                  otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                  });
              });       
        },
        mainControllers: function() {
            var exampleControllers = angular.module('exampleControllers', []);

            exampleControllers.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.child = {
                        name: 'test name',
                        profileImage: 'img/profile.png',
                        birthday:  '01/01/2014'

                };
            });

            exampleControllers.controller('ActionsCtrl', function($scope ,$location) {
                $scope.capturePhoto = function() {
                    $location.path('/action/capturePhoto');
                    app.camera.capturePhoto();
                };
            });

            exampleControllers.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.getLocation = function() {
                    app.geolocation.getLocation();  
                };
            }); 
        }
    },
    geolocation: {
        getLocation: function() {
            function onSuccess(position) {
                alert('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n'
                        + 'Longitude: ' + 
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it will be hard to manage just one single file as the application grows.

I also used to start my projects simple but always end up splitting into other files, something like:

```
js/
    app.js
    controllers.js
    services.js
    ...
```

And then even further

```
js/
    controllers/
        page1Ctrl.js
        page2Ctrl.js
        ...
```

I don't know about you, but for me indenting the code too much makes it hard to both write and read.

This is the approach I use to my angular apps:

```
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

app.controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.child = {
        name: 'test name',
        profileImage: 'img/profile.png',
        birthday: '01/01/2014'

    };
}]);

app.controller('ActionsCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.capturePhoto = function () {
        $location.path('/action/capturePhoto');
        app.camera.capturePhoto();
    };
}]);

app.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.getLocation = function () {
        app.geolocation.getLocation();
    };
}]);
```

The only downside is that you will have to include the js file in your index.html, each time you create it.

The array passed to angular's controller with the parameters names is for minification purposes, should you intend to use this.

Also note that you don't need to wait for 'deviceready' to start initializing the angular module.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following seed AngularJS project might be of help for you:

[Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)